# OpenVPN doesn't listen on port

Tags: server, openvpn

I configured OpenVPN on a Raspberry Pi on my local network.
I've done all configurations but I have one problem: the OpenVPN server doesn't use the port specified in `server.conf`. When I start NMAP on `localhost`, I don't see port 442.
How can I configure OpenVPN to listen on port 442?

Comment: Have you tried nmap on your local IP instead on localhost. Happens if you listen on eth0 and not lo.

Comment: I tried nmap on my local IP but there is also no port 442 open

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:
At the next day, I rebooted the client and than it worked.
I cant say what happend. Sorry